# Return value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my sql table, i have schema like,

```
username, FirstName, LastName, empID, manager
Jdoe      John       Doe       1234   Tango Charlie
Tcharlie  Tango      Charlie   5678   XYZ
```

I want to write a query that will give me, user's manager's empID.

so output should be,

```
Jdoe   John   Doe    1234   Tango Charlie   5678
```

I have like, 5000 records, and wanted to get a employeeID for all user's managers.

Comment: why have you tagged this with mysql, sql-server, AND oracle?  Which one is it?

Comment: Why oh why are you storing the managers first and last name as a concatenated value to indicate the manager of a particular user??? You should be storing the empID. What a nightmare you have here. Consider how ridiculous this is when a person changes their name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    yt1.username
  , yt1.firstname
  , yt1.lastname
  , yt1.empid
  , yt1.manager
  , yt2.empid
FROM dbo.YourTable yt1
JOIN YourTable yt2 ON yt1.manager = yt2.firstname + ' ' + yt2.lastname
```